# (MYSQL)Why can't I use 2 functions COUNT and MAX at the same time. MAX(COUNT(*))

Tags: mysql, database

Why can't I use 2 functions COUNT and MAX at the same time
But I can use 2 functions ROUND(AVG(abc))

Comment: Please make this a concrete question by including some actual MySQL queries.  The short answer here is that MySQL doesn't allow nesting aggregate functions (although some other databases do allow for it).  But, even in MySQL, aggregate functions can be nested if the outer one is being used as an analytic function.

Comment: Aggregate function needs in grouping expression. Imagine that nested aggregation is allowed. Inner aggregate function aggregates over this expression and obtains ONE row for this group. And then you should apply outer aggregate function to SINGLE ROW.